# SQL Disable Login

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server

I have to deliver a project with SQL Server database, the database login user will be created from the application code. And I don't want anyone to access to the database and prevent any login to the database expect the user which is created by the Application
Is there any way to disable all users expect one user in SQL Server?

I tried to disable (.\sqlexpress) to prevent anyone from accessing to this instance

Comment: Guess what? MySQL is a totally different product to SQL Server - do yourself a favour and correct your tags so the right experts look at your post.

Comment: _"And I don't want anyone to access to the database and prevent any login to the database expect the user which is created by the Application"_ - why do you want to do this? _Why don't you trust your own users?_ **What are you afraid of?** (Also, what you're asking is impossible: local Administrators can always get into any database on a system, regardless of SQL Server's `LOGIN` and `USER` permissions)

Comment: It includes login data for customers and the administrator shouldn't see this data

Comment: _It includes login data for customers and the administrator shouldn't see this data._ No kidding. Consider this: maybe you shouldn't be storing login data for customers in the database. Not in plaintext. Not encrypted. If you absolutely positively must store login credentials (and in this day and age of OAuth, etc. you really shouldn't) then consider using salt-and-hashing techniques to hash each customer's credentials with a unique salt.

Comment: In Microsoft SQL Server disabling a LOGIN is done by a REVOKE to the CONNECT privilege : REVOKE CONNECT TO MyLogin;